# C-array to NSData and back

Tags: iphone, malloc, nsdata

I'm attempting to save a c-style array of Vertex3D structs to an NSData object and get them back when reloading the app:

```
NSData *vert = [NSData dataWithBytes:&vertices length:(sizeof(Vertex3D) * NUM_OF_VERTICES)];
```

This data is then saved and attempted to be read back into my c-array thusly:

```
vertices = malloc(sizeof(Vertex3D) * NUM_OF_VERTICES);
[vert getBytes:&vertices length:(sizeof(Vertex3D) * NUM_OF_VERTICES)];
```

The above results in “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” followed by:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x48423c0: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

I'm very new to programming so there's probably some fundamental memory management principle I'm unaware of. I have verified that the loaded NSData is identical to the saved one, but it's clear that the transition from c-array to NSData (and back) is not as I intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to tell without seeing your declaration for the `vertices` variable, but using `&vertices` is probably wrong in the code you list in your question. If `vertices` is a C array, then it is already a pointer and you should omit the address operator `&`.

Comment: I've declared the vertices array thusly:    Vertex3D *vertices; I have tried omitting the     &. That stops it from crashing, but the array isn't filled properly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem was indeed my calling &vertices when saving the data (and loading too), which if I understand it correctly just saved a reference to memory instead of the data.